# Display Converted Time in Two Digit

Tags: java

I am displaying time duration in my android application. its working fine but its output is like

```
0.19
0.1
1.2
```

etc. Instead I want show it in two digit like

```
00.12
01.05
```

etc. My current code for get duration and display is like below

```
Date mDate = sdf.parse(startTime.getString(i));
long startTimeMilli = mDate.getTime();
mDate = sdf.parse(endTime.getString(i));
long endTimeMilli = mDate.getTime();
long sec = (endTimeMilli - startTimeMilli) / 1000;
String onlineTime = sec / 60 + ":" + sec % 60;
DetailLog log = new DetailLog(formatDate(startTimeMilli), onlineTime, formatDate(endTimeMilli));
mData.add(log);
```

Let me know if someone can help me to solve my issue. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.format("Value of a: %.2f", a) // for 2 decimal number ex. 1.03

String.format("Value of a: %.3f", a) // for 3 decimal number ex. 1.003

String.format("Value of a: %02d", a) // for 2 didgit ex. 01
```